# Import CA signed certificates to JKS

Tags: ssl, certificate, wso2, ca, wso2-identity-server

I got 4 `.crt` files from a CA as follows,

```
AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
demo_site_domain.crt
```

second and third are intermediate certificates. I want to import .crt file(s) to wso2carbon.jks store and replace it with the existing jks of a wso2 server as documented [here](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products/).
My problem is, document wants `wso2carbon` as the alias, but I can import only one certificate using that alias, therefore which .crt file should I import? Or should I import a composite .crt file which is created from above four crt files (is it possible?)
I tried with `AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt` and `demo_site_domain.crt` but after I set up the .jks file in the wso2 server, server url gives the following error,

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> The connection to ip:port was interrupted while the page was
>   loading.
>
> ```
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

What am I doing wrong here?

The wso2 server that I am using is `WSO2 UES` and I have to place the password in following four files to overcome the `Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect` error.

```
repository/conf/security/cipher-text.properties
repository/conf/identity.xml
repository/conf/carbon.xml
repository/conf/tomcat/catalina-server.xml
```

**UPDATE:**

I followed the answer given, but last command doesn't give the `installed in keystore` instead it is `Certificate was added to keystore`
following are my comands and repsponses ,

```
keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt -alias commoroot -trustcacerts
```

Enter keystore password:
Re-enter new password: 
Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias 
Do you still want to add it to your own keystore? [no]:  yes
Certificate was added to keystore

```
keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt -alias commointermediate1
```

Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore

```
keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt -alias commointermediate2
```

Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore

```
keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file demo_site_domain.crt -alias wso2carbon
```

Enter keystore password:
Certificate was added to keystore

Comment: How did you solve this problem ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Meta: I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate, but I can't find a good one. Answering anyway.)

[That page](http://wso2.com/library/knowledge-base/2011/08/adding-ca-certificate-authority-signed-certificate-wso2-products/) seems to be missing all of the dashes required on `keytool` commandline options and in PEM file formats; assuming you already corrected for that:

In item 3 it says "you might have to import any intermediate certificates ... before you can import your [CA-]signed certificate". In fact, you do. There are two ways to do this:

1: Import each cert *other than* your server (or other End Entity) cert, from the top down, to *separate* entries in the keystore; for your case:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file AddTrustExternalCARoot -alias somealias1 -trustcacerts
keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt -alias somealias2 
keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt -alias somealias3
```

where `somealias{1,2,3}` are aliases different from each other and different from any alias already in the keystore especially `wso2carbon`. **(edit)** (figured out how to get the code lines formatted correctly)

*Then* import your server cert to the **(edit) same alias in the same keystore file** where the `-genkeypair` and `-certreq` were **previously done** (or alternatively to an alias which is a **copy** in this keystore of the PrivateKey entry that was **earlier created** by `-genkeypair` and `-certreq`):
`keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file demo_site_domain.crt -alias wso2carbon`
This (last) step should say `Certificate reply was installed in keystore` NOT `Certificate was added to keystore`. Otherwise it actually failed, even though it didn't give an error message.

2: concatenate all the certs in one file, with the server (EE) cert first, and import that *combined* file to **(edit) the same alias in the same keystore file used earlier** (or to a copy of that privateKey entry):

```
# assuming any kind of Unix
cat demo_site_domain.crt COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt \
  COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt >combinedfile
# if Windows use copy a+b+etc or (for PEM) cut&paste in a plaintext editor like Notepad 
keytool -importcert -keystore wso2carbon.jks -file combinedfile -alias wso2carbon -trustcacerts
```

The order of the certs other than first doesn't actually matter *here*, but they will be stored in the keystore and used in the SSL/TLS protocol in "upward" order, so I use that order in the `cat` for consistency and clarity.

**(edit)** If there is at any time any doubt what entries you have or don't have in a given keystore file, you can list them with `keytool -list -v -keystore filename`. Any entry you generate with `-genkeypair` is a `PrivateKey` entry, and will contain *either* a self-signed cert automatically generated by `keytool` *or* a certificate *with* chain you have obtained from a CA. The display format is rather straggly and can be confusing, but look for the lines like `Certificate[1]:` `Certificate[2]:` etc. followed immediately by lines for `Owner:` (which means Subject in standard terminology) and `Issuer:`.
On the other hand each CA root or intermediate cert you import separately will be a `trustedCert` entry containing only that one cert.

Also the page says you need to import your "signed certificate" into `client-truststore.jks`. I believe that's wrong. You DO usually need to put a *self-signed* cert in any client truststore(s), but you should NOT need to do this for a cert signed by a well-known CA, which Comodo/Addtrust is. However, it *doesn't hurt* to add an unnecessary but valid cert to the truststore.

Comment: Note that you must use the same alias when importing the signed CSR reply that you used when generating the keypair. Otherwise they aren't associated.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I tried the first way but at last it gave `Certificate was added to keystore` not the installed, I updated the question with the steps I followed and the response <linux> Please have a look at the question's update section,

Comment: @IsuruGunawardana That can only mean you didn't follow the alias rule I mentioned above.

Comment: @EJP you man, `Certificate already exists in system-wide CA keystore under alias <debian:addtrust_external_root.pem>` this response come coz of that, I tried with different alias for `AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt` but same warning comes. other than that i followed wot u said. steps are added to questions update. please correct me where I am wrong

Comment: Sigh. That's a trust anchor. It is *your own* CA-signed certificate which must be added using the same alias as the keypair. Not a trust anchor.

Comment: @EJP I tried the exact way you mentioned but when importing the domain cert it gives the `Certificate was added to keystore' not the `installed` I'm sure I used different aliases as specified in the `UPDATE` and there's no any other aliases as same as these, as jks file was just get created in the first `keytool importcert...` command

Comment: There can be no doubt that you didn't. Otherwise it would have worked. I suggest you take it slowly, one step at a time, and copy down exactly what you're doing, and moist it al here. Not what you thought you did. What you did. In your question.

Comment: @Isuru you MUST NOT "create[] [the keystore] in the first keytool -importcert". You must use the *same keystore file* where the `-genkeypair` and `-certreq` were done, or at least a copy that already exists and contains the *exact same* privateKey entry that was previously created by the `-genkeypair`.

Comment: @EJP I did say that but apparently not strongly enough. editing.

Comment: You need to show how you created the original keypair and CSR.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 yes, that was the reason, I was trying by creating a new jks instead of keeping the jks which was at gen, Thank you for sharing ur thoughts.

Comment: So you were expecting an alias in one keystore to be magically associated with an alias in another keystore? That isn't a reasonable readingof what I wrote above.