# Import wildcard CA signed certificates to JKS

Tags: ssl

I have 3 `.crt` files from a CA as follows

- `ca1.crt`
- `ca2.crt`
- `__domain.com.crt`

I've tried to install them using the instruction described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948701/import-ca-signed-certificates-to-jks).

First, I tried to install them this way:

```
keytool -importcert -keystore server.jks -file ca1.crt -alias ca1
keytool -importcert -keystore server.jks -file ca2.crt -alias ca2
keytool -importcert -keystore server.jks -file __domain.com.crt -alias server
```

as a result `Certificate was added to keystore` is printed.

Then I tried another approach:

```
cat __domain.com.crt ca1.crt ca2.crt > combinedfile.pem
keytool -importcert -keystore server.jks -file combinedfile.pem -alias server -trustcacerts
```

The result is `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate`.

When I tried to check if RSA key exists in `.pem` file with `openssl rsa -in combinedfile.pem -text`, `unable to load Private Key` is printed.

What is the problem? Does it mean that there is an error in these `.crt` files?