# Tomcat SSL certificate authority invalid

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, rhel

Tried asking before but wasn't too good at it so heres attempt two

I'm trying to get SSL running on a tomcat 7 server under RHEL. Sever works fine under HTTP but when I try to access it with HTTPS, I get this error.

[image]

looking into it further, chrome tells me this

[image]

did some research. Added the certs to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors, update-ca-trust, still the same problem. tried rebuilding the keystore from scratch and changing up the order in which they were imported, still nothing.

Heres whats currently in my keystore:

```
root, Dec 29, 2017, trustedCertEntry,

tomcat, Dec 29, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry,

intermed, Dec 29, 2017, trustedCertEntry,

crm2.mydomain.org, Jan 3, 2018, trustedCertEntry,
```

and whats in my server.xml

```
<Connector
       port="443" maxThreads="200"
       scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true"
       keystoreFile="/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/conf/store" keystorePass=[pass]
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"/>
```

Other info:

Certs obtained from godaddy.
Used guide for installation [here](https://www.godaddy.com/help/tomcat-generate-csrs-and-install-certificates-5239)

godddy ssl checker says I'm missing the intermediate certificate

Tomcat version 7

RHEL 7.4

java 1.8

any help is appreciated

Comment: One question just to be sure that the problem isn't there: With what URL do you access your server? With the original domain name ([xyz].org) or with the direct IP (e.g. 192.168.0.15) because you're accessing your server from within your local are network?

Comment: We use the FQDN to access it. Its worth mentioning it's not on our network but this is an EC2 AWS instance

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be certain, but you appear to have NOT correctly followed the instructions you cite. Your keystore shows a trustedCertEntry with an alias that looks like a redaction of your domainname; this suggests you imported your server cert to that entry and not to the privateKeyEntry named 'tomcat'.

Quoting from the page you linked, emphasis added:

> To Install Your SSL [they clearly mean SSL/TLS Server Certificate] in Tomcat
>
> 1. Install the root certificate by running the following command:
>    keytool -import -alias root -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file [name of the root certificate]
> 2. Install the intermediate certificate by running the following command:
>    keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file [name of the intermediate certificate]
> 3. Install the **issued certificate [for your server]** into the keystore by running the following command:
>    keytool -import **-alias tomcat** -keystore tomcat.keystore -trustcacerts -file [name of the certificate]

On step 3 the alias is 'tomcat' which is the same alias you used for the -genkey[pair] and -certreq steps earlier in the procedure, NOT the name of your domain which typically is also the name of the file containing your server/EE cert.

To verify the correct procedure, keytool's response to commands 1 and 2 should be

```
 Certificate was added to keystore
```

but the response to command 3 should be DIFFFERENT:

```
 Certificate reply was installed in keystore
```

However, if you have 'rebuil[t] the keystore from scratch' and that includes generating a new keypair *after* obtaining the cert, the cert is now worthless and unusable and this procedure will not work; it will instead say something like

```
 Public keys in reply and keystore don't match
```

The cert that a server uses must match the private key, so this means you must follow the sequence specified in that page, and billions of other places: generate the keypair, *then* generate the CSR for *that* keypair, *then* get the CA to issue a cert from *that* CSR, *then* import *that* cert into the same keystore and alias, with its chain certs available either in the reply (as some CAs do, often with 'p7b' format) or elsewhere in the truststore (as GoDaddy apparently does).

Effectively dupe [Import CA signed certificates to JKS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948701/import-ca-signed-certificates-to-jks) for a different CA.

Comment: So then I guess my next question would be where to go from here because it sounds like I coulda broke stuff pretty hard. would it be easiest to blow away the server completely and try again from step 1 on a fresh install?

Comment: @SteakStyles: you certainly don't need to 'blow away' the whole server (i.e. Tomcat + app). Depending on what you did to the keystore that part may or may not be recoverable, but if you don't know what you did this will be difficult to figure out, so you are probably better off re-doing the _certificate_ process, from the step of creating a keypair (i.e. the beginning of the GoDaddy page).

Comment: I guess a question I should've asked upfront is if I remake the keystore with the exaxt same info I used when I first created it, do I still need to get fresh certs from go daddy, or can I use the original ones I received the first time?

Comment: @SteakStyles: You can't remake a keystore with the 'exact same info'; you may repeat the same _commands_ but every time you generate a keypair it is securely random and with overwhelming probability different from any and every other keypair you or anyone else in the universe has ever created or will ever create in all of space and time. If you can find or recover the old privatekey somewhere, you can use the old certs; if you have a new privatekey, you need new certs _matching that new key_.

Comment: Remade the keystore, followed the steps in the article, kept the aliases the same. Everything works! Thank you very much for your help!